# Непонятки с  callback function в JavaScript и VK API

Tags: callback, javascript, vkontakte-api

```
var isAuth = false;
   function __authInfo(response) {
      if (response.session)
        isAuth = true;
      else 
        isAuth = false;
    }

    function __wallPost(){
        if(isAuth){
                VK.Api.call('wall.post', {message: 'test api', attachment: 'photo61900_293400694'}, function(r) {
                  if(r.response) {
                    alert('Сообщение добавлено');
                  }
                });
            }else{
                VK.Auth.login(__authInfo);
                __wallPost();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('QwallPost').addEventListener('click', __wallPost, false);
```

__wallPost(); зацикливается, isAuth не меняет свое значение на true. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените `VK.Auth.login(__authInfo);` на

`Vl.Auth.login(function(response){
   __authInfo(response);
   __wallPost();
})`

Правда, если залогиниться не удастся, форма всплывет вновь.